# How to insert blank rows of a specific height for selection?

Tags: excel, vba

I have started an Excel macro to insert a blank row after selecting, but I want the blank `rowheight = 6`. I'm new to VBA, but am eager to learn.

This is for a project at work.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim FirstRow As Integer, xRows As Integer, xCols As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
FirstRow = WorkRng.Row
xRows = WorkRng.Rows.count
xCols = WorkRng.Columns.count
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WorkRng.Cells(xRows, 1).Resize(1, xCols).Select

Do Until Selection.Row = FirstRow
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Start on the right foot. Stop using On Error Resume Next until you know how. http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert rows, use code like `rows(3).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove` and to change column width use the `.ColumnWidth` property.  The code below inserts the spacer columns you mention.

```
Option Explicit
Sub insertSpacerColumns()
Dim r As Range, i As Integer, startCol As Integer, numSpacers As Integer
Set r = Application.InputBox("Select columns", , , Type:=8)
i = r(, 1).Column + 1
numSpacers = r(, r.columns.Count).Column - i + 1
Do
  columns(i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  columns(i).ColumnWidth = 1
  i = i + 2
  numSpacers = numSpacers - 1
Loop Until numSpacers = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `.RowHeight()` property:

```
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Offset(1,0).RowHeight = 6
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
```

...But please note it's best to [Avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/)

Comment: Thank you! I'm also having trouble adding spacer columns after selecting a group of columns, and I would also like them to be a specific width.